# Elapsed Time between start date and end date excluding weekend and holidays in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been searching for an Excel formula to calculate number of hours and minutes between a start date/time and an end date/time excluding weekends and holidays.

I'm unable to find one. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`NETWORKDAYS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7)

Comment: or [`NETWORKDAYS.INTL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28)

Comment: NETWORKDAYS function will help you.

Answer (score 0):

NETWORKDAYS is probably a great start.

FORMULA: =NETWORKDAYS(Start Date, End Date, Holidays)

Please see the example below.

[image]

Comment: This only gives the number of days. I need total hours, minutes, & seconds not including weekends & holidays.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to give you a quick response. There are  1440 minutes in day. If you apply that logic along with another part formula to deal with the minutes in the part days you would get your results.